# how to remove property label in new and edit actions?

Tags: symfony, yaml, symfony2-easyadmin, easyadmin

I use the `easyadmin` bundle in my `symfony` app for backend management.

I'd like to remove the label from some fields in the `edit` and the `new` view. I tried to use the same behaviour as in `formbuilder` :

```
form:
    fields:
        - {property: toto, label: false }
```

but the label is still displayed. Anyone knows the syntax to remove it ?

Comment: Did you try by setting the label to an empty string ? `label : ""`

Comment: if you add an empty string to the `label`, easyadmin use the humanized version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some are still arguing on [github](https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/issues/3028#issuecomment-566027902) to know if it has to be considered as a bug or not. Anyways a solution already exists.

#### Fixes

To remove the `label` in `easyAdim-bundle`, you need to do as for the `formbuilder` of `Symfony` where you can remove the label with options. To modify the `formbuilder` in `easy-admin` you use the `type_options` option. It goes the same for the label :

```
form:
    fields:
        - {property: toto, type_options: {label: false} }
```

will display a `form_row` with an empty label, without css, without Js and without empty labels

Answer (score 0):

By default the label use the "*humanized*" version of the property name.

In your case it would be **Toto** and the property ageOfToto would be **Age of toto**.

You cannot disable the label by setting it to false (you can for an action but not for a field), however you can set an empty string instead.

```
form:
    fields:
        - {property: toto, label: '' }
```

You could also override the template to not have a label see  [overriding easyadmin templates](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/edit-new-configuration.html#overriding-the-default-templates-using-symfony-s-mechanism).

Comment: if you add an empty string to the `label`, easyadmin use the humanized version. My objective is to avoid template overriding for something as simple as `label: false`

Comment: Maybe adding a css class to the property you want to hide the label and use a global javascript function to hide every label concerned ?

Comment: You can just `label: ' '` (add whitespace)